# C# Get type of property specified in Action

Tags: c#, action, gettype

I must create similar to Fluent API. I have DTO:
    `public class Foo { public string Bar {get;set;} }`

And i need to provide some properties (for example column name):

```
new MyFluentApi<Foo>().ColumnAttributes(**p => p.Bar**).ColumnName("Some very long column name where are Bar values")
```

In ColumnAttributes i need to get Type/name of specified property, but how? In expression p => p.Bar i get actual value of Bar, but i need type

Comment: How is ColumnAttributes defined? It should have an argument of type `Expression<Func<...>>`

Comment: This question would be better if you specified exactly what `ColumnAttributes` is. What is the argument? Some people might recognize it, but I don't. Once we have that the rest is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public static MyFluentApi<T> ColumnAttributes<T>(this MyFluentApi<T> api,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)selector.Body; // Assume expression is accessing a member of T
    var prop = (PropertyInfo)expression.Member; // Assume said member is a property
    var type = prop.PropertyType; // Get the type of property

    // Do something with type

    return api;
}
```

Note that if your lambda isn't a straight property access this will throw an exception.

An alternative would be to use type inference:

```
public static MyFluentApi<T> ColumnAttributes<T, TProp>(this MyFluentApi<T> api,
    Expression<Func<T, TProp>> selector)
{
    var type = typeof(TProp);

    // Do something with type

    return api;
}
```

Now this should work with any expression, regardless as to whether a property is accessed, which may or may not be what you're after.

For example, this would run without exception:

```
new MyFluentApi<Foo>().ColumnAttributes(p => new object());
```

Comment: What if we call a virtual method like `p => p.VirtualMethod()` and the static type of the object is T but the dynamic type of object if TDerived. How can we access derived type using `GetType`? Thanks.

Comment: @N.Dogac You mean get the runtime type? You could use a delegate directly e.g. `Func<T, object>`, invoke that and use `GetType()` on the result.

Comment: The delegate will want a parameter typed T if the signature is like this `Func<T, TProp>`, and the delegate invocation may have side effects in the program. Can we achieve this without invoking the delegate?

Comment: @N.Dogac This is an extension method of `MyFluentApi<T>`, so `T` can never be `TDerived` (unless `MyFluentApi<T>` is a covariant interface). If `TProp` references a derived type at runtime, the only way to get that type is to access the object and check its type using reflection.